# How to dynamically set scroll-height when using new css property 'position: sticky'?

Tags: javascript, css

Well, I met a problem in my work.
I want left sidebar to stick on top of the viewpoint of the mobile devices  when scrolled 100px height. Ok, I use

`position: fixed; position: sticky; position: -webkit-sticky; height: 100vh;`

But problem is that there is a fixed cart bar on the bottom which height is 100px;

I tried to use `bottom: 100px;` to dynamically change the height of the sidebar so I can scroll to bottom, but it doesn't work.

Comment: can we get a fiddle or live example?

Comment: any fiddle will be useful here